# youtube api v3 thumbnails not showing in IE 8 and 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I'm working on a project where I am showing a list of thumbnails of music videos using the youtube api v3.  It works perfectly fine for IE 10+ but it does not work for IE 8 or 9.  I was thinking maybe it could be that my jQuery version(1.9.1) might not be supported but according to jQuery's site version 1+ can support IE6+.
https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Right now I am stumped because I can't find any errors or anything and I am unsure how to proceed.

I was also speculating if it has something to do with using iframe but since I'm not embedding a video and just a thumbnail I figured I shouldn't need to use Youtube Iframe API.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
$.get(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyAHnfotDO49DlVtdRzZeZR0KoVo4DWZHNY",
  {
  part: 'snippet',
  q: query,
  maxResults: 8,
  type: 'video',
  },
  function(data){
     var output;
     var viewCount;

     $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
     //console.log(item);
     var videoId = item.id.videoId;
     var vidThumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
     //var vidURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=' + videoId;
     var videoTitle = item.snippet.title;


     $.get(
         "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAHnfotDO49DlVtdRzZeZR0KoVo4DWZHNY",
         {
         part: 'statistics',
         id: videoId
         },
         function(data){

             $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                 viewCount = '<p>Views: ' + item.statistics.viewCount + '</p>';

             });

         }
     );  
  output = '<li><iframe id="thumb" src="'+vidThumb+'" scrolling="no"></iframe><div class="info"><h3>' + videoTitle+ '</h3>' + viewCount + newLength + '<button type="button" class="cta" onclick="dlBundle(\'' + videoId + '\')"></button>' +'</div></li>';   

                  $('#searchResults').append(output);
```

Comment: I didn't post the whole thing and only picked and chose the relevant parts.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this for the thumbnail instead: item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url,

Comment: @IanS tried that and it didn't work.  I noticed the div with the id #searchResults isn't getting appended with the thumbnails.  So I'm thinking maybe jquery isn't firing or something.

Comment: I think it's failing on older browsers because they're less forgiving of syntax errors.  The javascript has several missing braces. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some braces etc.   Try this:

```
$.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyAHnfotDO49DlVtdRzZeZR0KoVo4DWZHNY",
            {
                  part: 'snippet',
                  q: query,
                  maxResults: 8,
                  type: 'video'
            },
            function(data)
            {
                var output;
                var viewCount;

                $.each(data.items, function(i, item)
                {
                     //console.log(item);
                     var videoId = item.id.videoId;
                     var vidThumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
                     //var vidURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=' + videoId;
                     var videoTitle = item.snippet.title;

                     $.get(
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAHnfotDO49DlVtdRzZeZR0KoVo4DWZHNY",
                            {
                                 part: 'statistics',
                                 id: videoId
                            },
                            function(data)
                            {
                                $.each(data.items, function(i, item)
                                    {
                                        viewCount = '<p>Views: ' + item.statistics.viewCount + '</p>';
                                    });
                            }
                        );  

        output = '<li><iframe id="thumb" src="' + vidThumb + '" scrolling="no"></iframe><div class="info"><h3>' + videoTitle+ '</h3>' 
                            + viewCount + newLength + '<button type="button" class="cta" onclick="dlBundle(\'' + videoId + '\')"></button>' +'</div></li>';   

                    $('#searchResults').append(output);
                });
            }

        );
```